# Linq lamda EXISTS() to find object with specific property

Tags: c#, linq

I need to find all employees who have subordinates with Exists() method in lamda expression. I totally have no idea to do this.

First i was trying to find employees who have a boss (Mgr) with this:

```cs
DataGrid.ItemsSource = Emps.Where(emp => Emps.Exists(m => m.Mgr != null));
```

but it doesn't work and it even dont makes sense.

I can't modify list, Emp class, xaml and i can't add new classes.

```cs
public List<Emp> Emps { get; set; }
```

```cs
public class Emp
{
    public int Empno { get; set; }
    public string Ename { get; set; }
    public int Sal { get; set; }
    public int? Comm { get; set; }
    public int Deptno { get; set; }
    public int? Mgr { get; set; }
    public DateTime HireDate { get; set; }
    public string Job { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to change the Exists to Any?

Comment: If i understand you right then ```DataGrid.ItemsSource = Emps.Where(emp => emp.Mgr != null);``` should do the trick.

Comment: @Yair I no, i have to use Exists.

Comment: @Artosz why do you have to use `Exists`? Is this a homework type thing where you're obligated to use that method?

Comment: @Rabban this return all employees, also with head boss who have no superior.

Comment: @gilliduck yes, it says that i have to use Exists

Comment: @Artosz this will return all employees that have a manager. Head bosses should not have a Manager and so they will not returned.

Comment: @Rabban https://ibb.co/tPnBGmJ this is my result

Comment: honestly the premise of this doesn't make sense to me. Not only are there far more efficient ways to do it, `Exists` just isn't the right tool. This is like trying to hammer in a nail with a screwdriver. Yeah eventually you'll get there, but you're gonna hate life doing it. 

Are you sure you've got the explanation correct? it just seems flawed from the get go to me.

Comment: Try this: `DataGrid.ItemsSource = Emps.Where(emp => emp.Exists(m => m.Mgr != (int?)null && m.Empno == emp.Empno));` Exists is not ideal here because it looks at the whole list and returns true all the time because there is at least one object that meets the criteria (at least one employee with a manager). That's why you are getting every object in the list returned. It doesn't make sense... but it should work.

Comment: This makes me sad. `Exists` is an older method and only applies to `List<T>`. So it's like when they tell someone to use `ArrayList`, except they've finally caught up with .NET 2.0. It's like in school where they tell you to write a paragraph and then tell you which words to use.

Comment: @gilliduck i think that one line makes no sense beacuse if in list is at least one who have boss then ALL employees will be returned

Comment: Which property on `Emp` even specifies that that employee has subordinates?

Comment: @dvo it also dont work

Comment: @devNull the is no property that specifies it. There is property Mgr that say who is superior

Comment: @dvo OK! it works! i only had to change `emp.Exists()` to `Emps.Exists()`!

Comment: @Artosz Oh, sorry. I mistyped that when I wrote it out. Good catch. It's an ugly work around, but it should work for this.

Comment: @dvo thanks a lot again

Comment: @Artosz happy to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
DataGrid.ItemsSource = Emps.Where(emp=> Emps.Exists(itm=> itm.Mgr.HasValue && emp.Empno == itm.Empno));
```